# Andriod Engineering Mode 1

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I rooted my Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 (SM-G7102) and it was successful. But ever since then the Engineering mode has been missing on my Android phone. I have tried the factory reset and yet the same result. I can't update my Android software, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"?  What exactly happens when you try to reboot into recovery mode?

Comment: @Izzy Not sure but I think OP meant "Engineer mode". In my Mediatek device I can access two kind of Engineer mode, 1) `*#*#4636#*#*` (available for most of the phones, name -> "Testing", activity-> `com.android.settings/.TestingSettings`);  2) name-> "EngineerMode", activity-> `com.mediatek.engineermode/.EngineerMode`, available for Mediatek devices usually. // Let's see which one is the case for OP. Could be a third case too. :) And based on the tag, may be OP is running [stock 4.3 JB](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_grand_2-5862.php).

Comment: Good points, @Firelord – I have no MTK device, but now that you've mention it I rawly remember having read that before. And you're most likely correct with the tag :) So let's wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: When I reboot in recovery my phone would turn off and won't on for 1hr and my play store is not working anymore .

Comment: @firelord I'm not sure I have two engineering modes and I tried different test mode and MTK app as well.

Comment: Enable USB debugging, setup [tag:adb] in PC, and enter this command: `am start -n com.android.settings/.TestingSettings` and tell us the result. Similarly, try `am start -n com.mediatek.engineermode/.EngineerMode`, but I haven't checked whether your device is an MTK device or not.

Comment: How do I install adb on my windows 8.1

Comment: @firelord how do i install adb on my windows 8.1

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 installed, so can't be of much help. Have you looked at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474)

Comment: @firelord no I don't think so